# find path to a key in JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a data represented by JSON. It might look like this:

```
$obj = {
  "lang": "en",
  "langLong": "english",
  "menu": ["Services", "About us", "Contact"],
  "pages": {
    "homepage": {
      "code": "homepage",
      "welcomeHeading": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "welcomeSubHeading": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "welcomeLink": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "aboutHeading": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "aboutSubHeading": "Ing. John Doe, FCCA",
      "aboutDescription": "Founder John Doe Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "ourServicesHeading": "Our services",
      "redBlocks": [
        {
          "heading": "Interim management",
          "items": ["first item", "second item"]
        },
        {
          "heading": "second service",
          "items": ["first item", "second item"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "services": {
      "code": "services",
      "welcomeHeading": "Interim management",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "heading": "Substitute interim management",
          "items": [
            {
              "subHeading": "target",
              "description": "
          "items": ["first item", "second item"]"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    }
}
```

I am serching for a function that consumes a key (eg. ourServicesHeading) and the Object and returns a path to the searching key.

I tried to write a function for that that is below. And one of the problems I am facing there is conversion between object and asociative array.

```
public function findPath($obj, $key) {
            $list = array();
            if(!$obj) {
                return $list;
            }
            if(is_array($obj)) {
                foreach ($obj as $item => $value) {
                    $list = array_merge($list,[$item]);
                }
                return $list;
            }
            if(in_array($key, (array) $obj)) {
                $list = array_push($list, $obj[$key]);
            }
            if(is_object($obj) && $obj != null) {
                $children = array_keys(json_decode(json_encode($obj), true));
                $obj = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
                if(sizeof($children) > 0) {
                    foreach($children as $item => $value) {
                        $result = $this->findValuesHelper($obj[$children[$item]], $key);

                        $list = array_merge($list, $result);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $list;
    }
```

and as a result from the function

```
$res = findPath($obj, "ourServicesHeading")
// "pages/homepage/ourServicesHeading"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need to keep on converting various parts from JSON and objects, you can convert the JSON to an array based representation using the second parameter of a single call to [`json_decode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

This code just converts the JSON to an array, then calls the `findPath()` method.  I've just used `print_r()` to output the results here for testing.

I've added comments to the code to explain the main code...

```
$json = json_decode($obj, true);

print_r(findPath($json, "ourServicesHeading"));

function findPath ( $obj, $key, $path = '' )    {
    $list = [];

    foreach ( $obj as $itemKey => $item )   {
        // Check if it's a field I'm interested in (force to string in case of a number)
        if ( (string)$itemKey == $key ) {
            // Add the matched item
            $list[] = $path."/".$itemKey;
        }
        if ( is_array($item) )  {
            // Recall this function again for next level of data, merge in the results
            $list = array_merge($list, findPath($item, $key, $path."/".$itemKey));
        }
    }

    // Pass up results
    return $list;
}
```

the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => /pages/homepage/ourServicesHeading
)
```

You will need to add the `public` and `$this->` parts as I've written it as an independent function.